# What size should my swap be, and my swapiness, when I am having OOM issues?

Tags: swap, memory-usage

What size should my swap be, and my swapiness, when I am having OOM (out of memory) issues?

What I am experiencing is complete slow down until frozen and the only thing that works in mouse pointer and it gets slower, by this stage too late to fix, cannot even ssh in.

HDD light is hammering away, and RAM indicators suggest I have used it all. even the clock stops.

after I boot back up Kernal Logs tell me: "Out of memory: Kill process 26899 (...) score 310 or sacrifice child"

I am running:

- **Ubuntu OS 18.04**
- **RAM: 32GB**
- **/swap 3GB partition on a velociraptor 150GB with 147GB of /home (just the 2)** Machine used to transcode, and heavy browsing. It is
- my daily desktop machine, it does not go to sleep.
- And I keep many tabs open in Firefox and Chrome.

My computing habits are possibly the issue but are not going to change much due to the nature of my job.

Chrome and Firefox both eat my RAM but nothing I can do about this. WOuld love to keep an eye on them with a notification, or limit them.
one or both possibly have many memory leaks, and it would be nice to find which is worse.

I find it difficult to get an accurate available RAM number and I use System Monitor in Gnome Top Bar.

Some kernal logs below:

cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
returns 0

**Should I change some stuff?**

I am thinking maybe more swap?
and more swapiness?

I cannot remember why I turned off swappiness (I am sure I did???), so not sure of the impact it would have.

Even just a notification when getting low would be ok

If I need more swap I will have to make/home smaller and increase swap, but to how much? I do not need to hibernate.

```
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815819+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843424] Mem-Info:
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815820+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843426] active_anon:6700209 inactive_anon:1113453 isolated_anon:0
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815823+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843426]  active_file:792 inactive_file:795 isolated_file:32
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815823+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843426]  unevictable:86 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815823+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843426]  slab_reclaimable:114513 slab_unreclaimable:51242
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815824+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843426]  mapped:427080 shmem:1189601 pagetables:52336 bounce:0
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815824+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843426]  free:50692 free_pcp:176 free_cma:0
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815824+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843427] Node 0 active_anon:26800836kB inactive_anon:4453812kB active_file:3168kB inactive_file:3180kB unevictable:344kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):128kB mapped:1708320kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:4758404kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 2048kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? yes
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815825+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843427] Node 0 DMA free:15884kB min:32kB low:44kB high:56kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15988kB managed:15884kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815825+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843429] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1873 31783 31783 31783
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815825+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843430] Node 0 DMA32 free:123472kB min:3980kB low:5896kB high:7812kB active_anon:1394728kB inactive_anon:363056kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:228kB unevictable:24kB writepending:0kB present:2022916kB managed:1957340kB mlocked:24kB kernel_stack:1088kB pagetables:11280kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:340kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815825+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843432] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 29910 29910 29910
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815826+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843434] Node 0 Normal free:63412kB min:63568kB low:94192kB high:124816kB active_anon:25406108kB inactive_anon:4090756kB active_file:2612kB inactive_file:3072kB unevictable:320kB writepending:0kB present:31178752kB managed:30634172kB mlocked:320kB kernel_stack:34576kB pagetables:198064kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:364kB local_pcp:120kB free_cma:0kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815826+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843435] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815828+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843436] Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB (U) 2*8kB (U) 3*16kB (U) 0*32kB 3*64kB (U) 2*128kB (U) 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15884kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815828+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843441] Node 0 DMA32: 891*4kB (UME) 172*8kB (UME) 667*16kB (UME) 1098*32kB (UME) 548*64kB (UME) 217*128kB (UME) 39*256kB (ME) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 123580kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815828+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843445] Node 0 Normal: 342*4kB (UME) 1147*8kB (UME) 1725*16kB (UME) 792*32kB (UME) 5*64kB (M) 1*128kB (M) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 63936kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815828+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843450] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815829+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843450] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815829+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843451] 1191363 total pagecache pages
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815829+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843452] 0 pages in swap cache
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815830+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843452] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815830+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843452] Free swap  = 2968572kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815830+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843453] Total swap = 2968572kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815831+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843453] 8304414 pages RAM
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815831+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843453] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815831+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843453] 152565 pages reserved
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815832+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843454] 0 pages cma reserved
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815833+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843454] 0 pages hwpoisoned
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815833+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843454] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815833+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843460] [  410]     0   410    11762      576   118784        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815835+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843464] [ 1248]   106  1248    13180      688   143360        0          -900 dbus-daemon
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815871+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843479] [ 1553]   123  1553   356103    41077   692224        0             0 mysqld
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815842+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843477] [ 1463]     0  1463    18074      189   180224        0         -1000 sshd
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815874+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843484] [ 7772]     0  7772   444853   167204  1888256        0             0 Xorg
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815875+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843487] [ 7971]   130  7971  4139617  1641335 14372864        0             0 jsvc
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815876+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843487] [ 8213]   130  8213   360244    10081   786432        0             0 mongod
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815842+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843477] [ 1463]     0  1463    18074      189   180224        0         -1000 sshd
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815883+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843502] [ 8762]  1000  8762  1168733   175414  2805760        0             0 gnome-shell
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815884+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843503] [ 8809]  1000  8809   927950     3566   630784        0             0 pulseaudio
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815897+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843526] [ 9038]  1000  9038   407630    16845   929792        0             0 nautilus-deskto
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815929+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843540] [24933]  1000 24933   713935    55265  2007040        0             0 nautilus
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815932+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843545] [18151]  1000 18151  3110421   466608  8593408        0             0 firefox
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815932+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843546] [18209]  1000 18209  1527811   632286 13004800        0             0 Web Content
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815934+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843546] [18272]  1000 18272  1148444   344039  7467008        0             0 WebExtensions
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815934+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843547] [18477]  1000 18477  1120696   252293  8085504        0             0 Web Content
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815936+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843553] [18131]  1000 18131  1070693   219756  6922240        0             0 Web Content
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815938+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843556] [11701]  1000 11701  1117852   248545  6672384        0             0 Web Content
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815938+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843557] [25083]  1000 25083  1115243   283290  7639040        0             0 Web Content
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815939+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843557] [25121]  1000 25121   972894   115746  5341184        0             0 Web Content
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815939+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843558] [26440]  1000 26440  1181471   310589  8720384        0             0 Web Content
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815943+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843565] [29162]  1000 29162  1126221   272709  8159232        0             0 Web Content
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815944+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843566] [25397]     0 25397   713116     4125   487424        0          -900 snapd
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815949+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843578] [12407]  1000 12407  3330427   163801  2134016        0             0 java
...
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815954+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843584] [26899]  1000 26899   527162    88831  3940352        0           300 QtWebEngineProc
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815969+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843593] [18683]  1000 18683  6068998    41557  5480448        0             0 slack
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815973+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843603] [ 2408]  1000  2408   138910     8547   925696        0           200 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815974+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843604] [ 2412]  1000  2412   133640     5987   860160        0           200 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815975+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843604] [ 2498]  1000  2498   182900     4300  1265664        0           300 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815975+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843605] [ 2511]  1000  2511   182866     4230  1273856        0           300 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815975+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843606] [ 2600]  1000  2600   185217     5757  1458176        0           300 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815976+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843606] [ 2636]  1000  2636   182077     4535  1261568        0           300 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815976+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843607] [ 2653]  1000  2653   182205     4996  1314816        0           300 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815976+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843608] [ 2938]  1000  2938   187762     7636  1593344        0           300 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815977+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843609] [ 3222]  1000  3222   207255    12759  2572288        0           300 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815977+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843610] [ 3610]  1000  3610   176509     3832  1060864        0           300 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815978+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843611] [ 6970]  1000  6970   111138     2749   548864        0           300 chrome
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815978+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843612] Out of memory: Kill process 26899 (QtWebEngineProc) score 310 or sacrifice child
2019-12-13T09:57:33.815978+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.843656] Killed process 26899 (QtWebEngineProc) total-vm:2108648kB, anon-rss:191316kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:164008kB
2019-12-13T09:57:33.816832+13:00 myserver kernel: [1155672.855879] oom_reaper: reaped process 26899 (QtWebEngineProc), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:164692kB
2019-12-13T10:03:23.550542+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291628] Purging GPU memory, 0 pages freed, 20709 pages still pinned.
2019-12-13T10:03:26.543167+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291632] 1 and 0 pages still available in the bound and unbound GPU page lists.
2019-12-13T10:03:26.914609+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291908] mongod invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
2019-12-13T10:03:27.235869+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291910] mongod cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
2019-12-13T10:03:30.067478+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291921] CPU: 5 PID: 2731 Comm: mongod Tainted: G           OE    4.15.0-70201911191317-generic #0+mediatree+hauppauge-Ubuntu
2019-12-13T10:03:31.614913+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291924] Hardware name: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.M./Z370 Gaming-ITX/ac, BIOS P1.10 09/21/2017
2019-12-13T10:03:32.735347+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291926] Call Trace:
2019-12-13T10:03:33.267410+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291940]  dump_stack+0x63/0x8e
2019-12-13T10:03:37.614982+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291947]  dump_header+0x71/0x285
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631003+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291954]  ? security_capable_noaudit+0x4b/0x70
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631589+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291959]  oom_kill_process+0x21f/0x420
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631589+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291964]  out_of_memory+0x116/0x4e0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631590+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291970]  __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xa53/0xe00
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631590+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291978]  ? alloc_pages_current+0x6a/0xe0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631590+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291984]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x29a/0x2c0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631590+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291990]  alloc_pages_current+0x6a/0xe0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631591+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.291997]  __page_cache_alloc+0x81/0xa0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631592+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292001]  filemap_fault+0x3ea/0x6f0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631592+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292006]  ? page_add_file_rmap+0x134/0x180
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631592+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292010]  ? filemap_map_pages+0x181/0x390
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631592+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292015]  ext4_filemap_fault+0x31/0x44
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631592+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292020]  __do_fault+0x5b/0x115
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631593+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292026]  __handle_mm_fault+0xdef/0x1290
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631593+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292033]  handle_mm_fault+0xb1/0x210
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631594+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292040]  __do_page_fault+0x281/0x4b0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631594+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292044]  ? SyS_futex+0x13b/0x180
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631594+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292050]  do_page_fault+0x2e/0xe0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631594+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292056]  ? page_fault+0x2f/0x50
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631594+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292061]  page_fault+0x45/0x50
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631595+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292065] RIP: 0033:0x56528c4b5099
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631595+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292068] RSP: 002b:00007f942f06eb80 EFLAGS: 00010246
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631595+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292072] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007f943332c1aa
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631596+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292074] RDX: 0000565290b10588 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000565290b10588
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631596+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292075] RBP: 00007f942f06ebf0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000565290b105b0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631597+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292077] R10: 00007f942f06e9f0 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: 000056529082d400
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631598+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292079] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000565290b99000 R15: 0000565290b3c000
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631598+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292083] Mem-Info:
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631598+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292094] active_anon:6651747 inactive_anon:1163147 isolated_anon:0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631598+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292094]  active_file:867 inactive_file:723 isolated_file:0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631599+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292094]  unevictable:86 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631599+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292094]  slab_reclaimable:114335 slab_unreclaimable:51239
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631599+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292094]  mapped:442521 shmem:1239300 pagetables:51808 bounce:0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631600+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292094]  free:50717 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631600+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292101] Node 0 active_anon:26606988kB inactive_anon:4652588kB active_file:3468kB inactive_file:2892kB unevictable:344kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:1770084kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:4957200kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 2048kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? yes
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631601+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292103] Node 0 DMA free:15884kB min:32kB low:44kB high:56kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15988kB managed:15884kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631601+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292111] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1873 31783 31783 31783
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631601+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292119] Node 0 DMA32 free:123524kB min:3980kB low:5896kB high:7812kB active_anon:1381784kB inactive_anon:378740kB active_file:16kB inactive_file:140kB unevictable:24kB writepending:0kB present:2022916kB managed:1957340kB mlocked:24kB kernel_stack:1072kB pagetables:10716kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631602+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292128] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 29910 29910 29910
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631602+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292135] Node 0 Normal free:63460kB min:63568kB low:94192kB high:124816kB active_anon:25225204kB inactive_anon:4273848kB active_file:3456kB inactive_file:2752kB unevictable:320kB writepending:0kB present:31178752kB managed:30634172kB mlocked:320kB kernel_stack:34320kB pagetables:196516kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631603+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292143] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631603+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292150] Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB (U) 2*8kB (U) 3*16kB (U) 0*32kB 3*64kB (U) 2*128kB (U) 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15884kB
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631603+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292175] Node 0 DMA32: 971*4kB (UME) 223*8kB (UME) 694*16kB (UME) 1122*32kB (UME) 527*64kB (UME) 216*128kB (UME) 37*256kB (ME) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 123524kB
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631604+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292200] Node 0 Normal: 705*4kB (UME) 1154*8kB (UME) 1751*16kB (UME) 731*32kB (UME) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 63460kB
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631604+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292223] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631604+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292225] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631605+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292227] 1240898 total pagecache pages
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631605+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292231] 0 pages in swap cache
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631605+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292233] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631605+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292234] Free swap  = 2968572kB
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631606+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292236] Total swap = 2968572kB
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631606+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292237] 8304414 pages RAM
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631606+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292239] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631607+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292240] 152565 pages reserved
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631607+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292241] 0 pages cma reserved
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631607+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292243] 0 pages hwpoisoned
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631607+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292244] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
2019-12-13T10:03:37.631608+13:00 myserver kernel: [1156021.292263] [  393]     0   393   122557      807   999424        0             0 systemd-journal
```

Comment: /swap is probably swap file. A partition would not show up there and Ubuntu now enables swap files by default. I'd say turn on swappines, set value to something like 10 at first, then increase if issue persists. You may want to add additional swap files as necessary. There are instructions on how to do all that and I also have a script to add swap files as necessary, so let me know if you need that

Comment: When an OOM event is in progress, it is irrelevant what size swap or swappiness should be, because you can't change them. IMO, the following should be done in order of importance: 1-more ram, 2-adjust usage habit, 3-more swap and swappiness.

Comment: Reveal some of your computing habits that allow you to bring a 32 GB RAM machine to it's knees. You never reboot the machine? You never close browsers? I would have the biggest trouble filling my 16 GB RAM. I can only imagine such scenario with highly specific high ram using processes, not with ordinary desktop use.

Comment: Yes browser use is high and I suspect memory leakage is the cause, multiple gmail mailboxes open, plus security system seems to use 18%.

Comment: saw: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265713/how-to-configure-swappiness-in-linux-memory-management
Looks like my 0 should be a 1, to prevent OOM.

Comment: Computing habits, correct not closing browsers often, unless I see RAM being maxed, shouldn't have to with 32GB.
But if RAM is not nearly maxed out then it is wasted.
I like the idea of more RAM but running itx board.

Comment: Agree more ram would be great - too expensive. Change habits - should not be needed.
Question still remains how much swappiness (so far 10 suggested), and how much swap (currently 3GB), and why?

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265713/how-to-configure-swappiness-in-linux-memory-management

```
vm.swappiness = 0   # Swap is disabled. In earlier versions, this meant that the kernel would swap only to avoid an out of memory condition, but in later versions this is achieved by setting to 1.
vm.swappiness = 1   # Kernel version 3.5 and over, as well as kernel version 2.6.32-303 and over: Minimum amount of swapping without disabling it entirely.
vm.swappiness = 10  # This value is sometimes recommended to improve performance when sufficient memory exists in a system, this value *10* could be considered for the performance being expected. 
vm.swappiness = 60  # The default value.
vm.swappiness = 100 # The kernel will swap aggressively.
```

@sergly suggested 10, if I get no improvement with 1 I will try 10.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

```
RAM   No hibernation    With Hibernation  Maximum
32GB             6GB                38GB     64GB
```

Trying 6GB, to give a little more headroom, then will monitor its usage.